# My mesh deforms to original placement

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

I tried resetting the position in pose mode with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to no avail.

I was guessing it has something to do with the default pose but I haven't found any way that seems to work.

Just tried setting rest pose and still not fixed.

[Zip with the blend](https://www.sendspace.com/file/st14i2)

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please don't ask the same question twice. If you need to add information to a question you can use the [edit] link below it.

Comment: My fault sorry I thought I deleted the other. Will do now

Comment: The bone is driven by Wrist-ik.L Select it in pose mode and alt+g.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong, I also tried deleting the armature vertex groups and re-parenting with automatic weights and it still persisted. I noticed some change when I re-set it in pose mode while it was un parented but when I ended up re-parenting it the problem hadn't gone away.